# How to insert a Picture and fit it in <head> tag

Tags: html, css

this is my problem:

```
<!Demo html>
<html>
<head>

 <img src="html\111.jpg" alt="can't be displayed" align="center">

</head>

<body>

</body>
```

---

and i just want to fit the picture onto the screen

Comment: Why do you want to do that? `img` tags go inside `body`.

Comment: Also better use slashes instead of backslashes in an url.

Comment: Out of html and programming standards.

Comment: `  <!DOCTYPE html>` and  `img` inside head tag? -_-

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In this snippet just replace src code with your link.

```html
<!Demo html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 .img{
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
} 
 </style>
</head>

<body>
<img src="http://wallpapersrang.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/wallpapers-for-3d-desktop-wallpapers-hd.jpg" alt="can't be displayed" align="center" class="img">
</body>
```

Comment: `<!Demo html>` can you guys explain it??

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want the image to cover the screen, then this is the simplest solution to your problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


</head>

<body>
 <img src="html\111.jpg" alt="can't be displayed" align="center" width="100%" height="100%">
</body>
```

But if your intention is actually to use the image as a background, I would strongly suggest adding it as a background image (with CSS) to the body element.

Edit:

With css:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: url( html/111.jpg ) 100% 100%;
}
```

Also, don't forgot to link to your .css in your .html file.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
```

Comment: `<!Demo html>` can you guys explain it??

Comment: I didn't notice that typo. I am sincerely sorry, but I cannot explain it.

Comment: it is doesn't fill all the screen look at the edges of the result

Comment: @ahmadfakeer That's probably because the <body> element is not 100% width and height of the <html> element, see my updated answer for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

For inside a head tag......

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <style type="text/css">
   body { background: url(url of the image) !important; }
   </style>
   </head>
  <body>
    yourbody
    </body>
  </html
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="html/111.jpg" alt="can't be displayed" align="center" width="100%" height="100%">
  </header>
</body>
```